# limit total number of results in solr

Tags: solr, solr4

I want to limit the total numbers of results in a solr response.

Lets say I have 200 records in response.I am using pagination start=0,rows=10.

I want to limit it 100.So even though if we try start=100 and row=110.it should not gives us any response.

Is there any way I can fix the total results?

Any Inputs?

Thanks.

Comment: You question is unclear. Do you want to limit the pagination feature?

Comment: I want to limit the total results to limited number. Inside the limit pagination should work normally.

Comment: That's probably way better handled in your controller logic. Your only option that I can think of is to lock rows to 100 and start to 0, so that you always get up to 100 documents back and never any more than that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use pagination with SolrQuery with solr . you can use query.setStart(100) , query.setRows(110) to limit no of rows to be returned by query .

in your case  this function can be used as  query.setStart(100) i.e start of your result , and  query.setRows(110) will be end of your result ..

this will return document starting from 100 to 110 in response